# Django Invalid HTTP_HOST header from suspicous domain

Tags: security, python, http, deployment, django

I am getting warnings on my Django deployment server. To be precise:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'ip.ws.126.net:443'.

The WHOIS entry for this domain is pretty opaque just as the domain: https://www.whois.com/whois/126.net

My question is:
**What is the origin of these warnings?** I suspect some kind of webcrawling but I don't understand the security aspect behind the warning.

Just asking out of curiousity, maybe someone can explain.

Comment: Hello there! Have you found the reason behind that? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Yes, this is a good hint:
https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/914#issuecomment-263614761
These are apparently scripts checking for vulnerabilities on your server. I get quite consistently 2-3 requests of these a day. More on Host Header attacks:
https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/automated-detection-of-host-header-attacks/

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the reply!